# Finding Next Obstacle in List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a game that moves to the end of a square. Inside the game I created obstacles by making a list of true and false (false=obstacles). What I have (but did not post) is something that detects an obstacle ONLY IF the user lands on the obstacle. However, I want to find a way to detect an obstacle BEFORE the user makes its next move and make it stay in place if the next spot will be an obstacle. In other words I want to find the next index of list before proceeding. Here's some pseudo code for a better picture:

```
if next_left != [[False]]: # if there is no obstacle
    officially_move_left
else: # if there is an obstacle
    user_do_nothing
```

What I have (in pseudo):

```
 def moving_pos(user):       
   copy_user.pos = user.pos
   if  copy_user.pos +1 == [True]
       user.pos += 1
       copy_user.pos += 1
    else:
        return user.pos
```

Comment: So you want to find in which all locations in your list the value is False .?/

Comment: I think some more detail in your implementation would be helpful, how are you holding the true/false? Does your character move inside a fixed zone? Do we know where it currently is, coordinate-wise?

Comment: if the user moves left, right, front, or back, i want it to detect whether the next spot they want to move to will be either true or false. for example, if user wants to move right, the spot they want to move to must not have an obstacle. If it does, they will stay in place.

Comment: Do they move one square at a time?

Comment: yes, they move one square at a time.

Comment: You probably want something like `dx, dy = {"left":(0,1),"up":(1,0),"right":(0,-1),"down":(-1,0)}[next_direction]; if board[curr_y + dy][curr_x + dx]: ...`

Answer (score 4):

```
if (user_position == obstacle):
    next_square_is_obstacle = true
    user_move_backwards
```

ie, move the player, detect the object, move the player back again. It's very difficult to help without seeing the actual implementation

---

Edit: Okay, in your new edit I don't see any reason why the program should have such constraints. However, let me suggest something new-

```
obstacle_index = [obs1, obs2, obs3...]
if user_position+1 in obstacle_index:
    do_nothing;
else
    user_move_forward;
```

Can you post the actual minimal working code, or at least a more detailed pseudocode of the implementation?